# ExtJS 4.2.1 - writing a program with `requires` without using ext-debug.js as a core

Tags: javascript, extjs

My problem is short and simple. I've got the basic example set up as described by the Ext JS team (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/application_architecture) but currently it only works with ext-debug.js.

I'd like to use the ext.js-core itself, but that doesn't allow me to use dynamic loading, thus forces me to use ext-all.js, which is a huge honking script of which 80% I don't need (abstractables and extended classes not included).

It is possible to write my Ext.Application in ext-debug.js for development and then switch live to ext.js?

**/edit**

I found this wonderful documentation, which doesn't explain why a minified version of ext-debug (thus ext.js) doesn't work, but there you go.

1. ext-debug.js - This file is only for use during development. It provides the minimum number of core Ext JS classes needed to get up and running. Any additional classes should be dynamically loaded as separate files as demonstrated above.
2. ext.js - same as ext-debug.js but minified for use in production. Meant to be used in combination with your application's app-all.js file. (see section 3)
3. ext-all-debug.js - This file contains the entire Ext JS library. This can be helpful for shortening your initial learning curve, however ext-debug.js is preferred in most cases for actual application development.
4. ext-all.js - This is a minified version of ext-all-debug.js that can be used in production environments, however, it is not recommended since most applications will not make use of all the classes that it contains. Instead it is recommended that you create a custom build for your production environment as described in section 3.

Comment: Not sure what's going on in your case, because the ext.js file should work...try using the ext-all-dev.js it gives you a little more warnings about potential issues. but you should also take a look at Sencha cmd it can build a custom package for you, minified with only the ext stuff you need and your code.

Answer (score 1):

The key is here:

> Meant to be used in combination with your application's app-all.js file

Your application(and all the dependencies) should be compiled into single file `app-all.js` (you can do it with help of the sencha sdk). Your html should look like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/extjs/ext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/app-all.js"></script>
```

> I'd like to use the ext.js-core itself, but that doesn't allow me to use dynamic loading

There shouldn't be any dynamic loading as all the javascript is compiled into those two files (ext.js and app-all.js).

Answer (score 0):

Use ext-dev.js instead of ext-debug.js to get dynamic loading *and* comments. Use [Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/command) to build the production JavaScript and CSS files.